# Cannot connect to Amazon S3

Tags: 7

Whenever I try to save the bucket name I get these errors:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_CLOSEPOLICY - assumed 'CURLOPT_CLOSEPOLICY' in RequestCore->prep_request() (line 626 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/clickbus-cms/sites/all/libraries/awssdk/lib/requestcore/requestcore.class.php).
Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLCLOSEPOLICY_LEAST_RECENTLY_USED - assumed 'CURLCLOSEPOLICY_LEAST_RECENTLY_USED' in RequestCore->prep_request() (line 626 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/clickbus-cms/sites/all/libraries/awssdk/lib/requestcore/requestcore.class.php).
Warning: curl_setopt() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in RequestCore->prep_request() (line 626 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/clickbus-cms/sites/all/libraries/awssdk/lib/requestcore/requestcore.class.php).
Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_CLOSEPOLICY - assumed 'CURLOPT_CLOSEPOLICY' in RequestCore->prep_request() (line 626 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/clickbus-cms/sites/all/libraries/awssdk/lib/requestcore/requestcore.class.php).
Notice: Use of undefined constant CURLCLOSEPOLICY_LEAST_RECENTLY_USED - assumed 'CURLCLOSEPOLICY_LEAST_RECENTLY_USED' in RequestCore->prep_request() (line 626 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/clickbus-cms/sites/all/libraries/awssdk/lib/requestcore/requestcore.class.php).
Warning: curl_setopt() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in RequestCore->prep_request() (line 626 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/clickbus-cms/sites/all/libraries/awssdk/lib/requestcore/requestcore.class.php).
```

And the configuration is not saved.
The bucket name contains "-", would this be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got the answer. After PHP 5.5, these constants were removed!

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68147